# How can I get debug log in Mavensmate

Tags: mavensmate

Following a lot of people's advice, I am trying to use Mavensmate. Coming from developer console, there are still things I am not used to. One thing is I can't find where the debug log is. I tried everything I can think of under Mavensmate > debugging, but it seems to just processing for a while and then tell me it is a pass - but where is the log?

I assume that the debug log is not auto-generated like in developer console - so need to generate either a quick or debug log before opening it. Is that correct?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows and chrome

Comment: (MavensMate author here) Here's the associated documentation: http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Debugging

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you need to first start the log capturing process via:

> MavensMate > Debugging > New Debug Log

[image: Start Log capturing in MavensMate]

Then perform your actions that will be logged.

Finally, pull the resulting logs down using

> MavensMate > Debugging > Fetch Logs

By default they will be placed in **project/debug/logs** and should appear in the folders ready to be opened.

[image: Open Debug log in MavensMate]

---

As an interesting aside. When you do an "New Debug Log", MavensMate will create a new [TraceFlag](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_traceflag.htm) record via the tooling API:

[image: TraceFlag]

This tells Salesforce the type of logs to capture, the logging levels, and when to stop capturing them.

You can then query the [ApexLog](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm) sObject to get the resulting ids and pull the log bodies down.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there a way I can filter the log?

Comment: @LanceShi I don't think there is currently anything natively within MavensMate that will parse the log file. I really like Mavens for coding Apex and Visualforce, but use [a tool of my own design](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-Apex-Logs.aspx) for working with logs, testing and anonymous apex. You can also still use the develop console for log processing. You will find they appear there as well.

Comment: (MavensMate author here) You can also use the "Scrub log" command to filter the fetched logs down to USER_DEBUG and EXCEPTION statements.