# How can I generate debug logs when I run unit tests from MavensMate?

Tags: unit-test, logging, mavensmate

Generating and viewing debug logs in MavensMate has been [clarified before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/how-can-i-get-debug-log-in-mavensmate) and works great for me - I especially like the Scrub feature. However, I can't generate a log when I run unit tests.

To replicate my problem, here is a simple test:

```
@isTest
private class TestingTestClass {

    @isTest static void test_method_one() {
        System.debug('I would like to see this in my debug log');
        System.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

}
```

Here is my configuration that is used by Quick Log to register the trace flag:

```
{
    "levels": {
        "Workflow": "INFO", 
        "Callout": "INFO", 
        "System": "DEBUG", 
        "Database": "INFO", 
        "ApexCode": "DEBUG", 
        "Validation": "INFO", 
        "Visualforce": "DEBUG"
    }, 
    "users": [
        "005i0000001qYYLAA2"
    ], 
    "expiration": 480
}
```

When I use my browser and go to `Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs` I can see my trace flag correctly registered under monitored users and the filters are the same as specified.

To make sure this is in fact the user under which Unit Tests are run, I go to `Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution`, run my sample test and check the username

[image: Checking which user runs unit tests]

The test run generate a debug log as expected.

So, I clear all the logs and from Sublime launch a Unit test run when I set the log level like this:

[image]

That does not generate any log output. (I do a fresh browse to `Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs` and there are no logs)

Any help very much appreciated. Running Sublime Text, with MavensMate v3.5.0 talking to a Salesforce sandbox on Summer 14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually I get the logs in these tab that opens on the far right of hitherto screenshot you showed...there's about 5 things in there, including the debug, code coverage, and some other things.

Comment: Aha! That little triangle on the Test Results tab - indeed it opens up a whole world of information. Very useful. Couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. Thanks, Shane!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a screen capture to go with @Shane's response:

[image: Mavens Test Results Image]