# Get Debug Logs from Salesforce with MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate, logging, debug

I'm working with MavensMate v0.0.11-beta7 and using Salesforce API v.38 in configuration. I would like to get Debug Logs from Salesforce with MavensMate in order to open the files with Sublime Text.

I have Started Logging with MavensMate as it can be observed in the image:

[image]
After that new trace flag is created in Salesforce.

Now my problem is how can be the Debug Logs downloaded. I have created the folder [my_project_folder]/debug/logs and I have follow this previous post in StackExchange ([link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/how-can-i-get-debug-log-in-mavensmate?rq=1)) but with my version of MAvensMate I don't have the options of "Fetch Logs".

This question is not the same like the question linked in the previous paragraph because "Fetch Logs" option is not present in my Mavensmate version and debug logs aren't downloaded in a automatic way. So, how can I pull to get the logs via Mavensmate?

[image]

Comment: If this gets closed as off topic or you do not get an answer the official support is located here: https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues

Comment: Why would you want that? MavensMate doesn't handle logs very well, IMO. I use MavensMate and always have the Dev. Console open in a browser tab if I need the logs. I recommend you to use this as well.

Comment: Thanks Renato but I prefer to review my code and see logs in the same place (Sublime). Is easy to switch between tabs. I dont want to open Developer Console just to see Logs and review my code and do other things in Sublime

Comment: @murcix - Given that you like everything in one place, give Illuminated cloud and IntelliJ a try. Not sure if that is something you are willing to try by switching to that or any other IDE would provide you a much better experience IMHO. With IC you can even debug and step through your logs for a given transaction which takes it to a whole new level...

Comment: @RenatoOliveira - In a DE environment having the dev console open to listen for logs consumes a lot of API calls and you could easily be locked out of the org for 24 hours (external tools) until the API limit is reset....

Comment: @Eric and that's why I open the dev console only when I need to debug some application routine or test. If I'm doing other thing then the console is not open or is inactive.

Comment: I just would like to have the same functionality as previous version of Mavensmate as is mentioned in this thread (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/how-can-i-get-debug-log-in-mavensmate?rq=1) Changing programing IDE is not an option for me. I'm really satified with Sublime

Comment: @murcix - No worries, it was just an options. I felt the same as you until TLS1.1 was enabled in sandboxes and MM was dead in the water for a while.....I have never looked back. Ultimately the best tool is the one you can use most effectively.

Comment: Thumbs up for Illuminated Cloud!!! after years of struggling with eclipse and mavens mate, Illuminated Cloud is the best IDE for Salesforce (for now)

Answer (score 2):

> Streaming debug logs are currently not operational on v37.0 of the
>   Salesforce API. Use 36.0 if you require debug logs.

Source: [Releases · joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop · GitHub](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop/releases)

Comment: I'm using API version38

Comment: Can you check to see if using API version 36 resolves your issue?

Comment: With API 36 is working. Since I'm using Global Picklist I can't use API 36,  that's the reason because I'm asking using 38.