# Debug window in Sublime text3

Tags: debugging, mavensmate, sublime

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with MavensMate.
However, I'm using Developer Console for checking debug log.

How do I see debug log in Sublime?

I saw already article below.
[How can I get debug log in Mavensmate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/how-can-i-get-debug-log-in-mavensmate)

However, my MavensMate | debugging options are different.

[image]

and After Start Debugging, when I click Flush, Sublime said that No Debug directory. and I couldn't find log file on the side file tree.

Please help.
It really distress me...

---

+
[image]

Comment: That answer is for an older version of mavensmate. If you open the mavensmate client app and look at the settings, do you have the "MM_LOG_LOCATION" and/or "MM_LOG_LEVEL" settings filled in? You need those for logging to work.

Comment: @JohnTowers Thanks. I set up the "MM_LOG_LOCATION" and "MM_LOG_LEVEL" already, and there is still no log file on my file tree, left side bar... Please keep helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you've had no other luck, you can always just download the debug log from the Developer Console and just open it in Sublime to view.